# ACTION_INSERT and ACTION_EDIT change background color

Tags: android

is it possible to change background color of ACTION_INSERT and ACTION_EDIT?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setData(ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(id)));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
// for return back to application
intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);

Context context = getReactApplicationContext();
context.startActivity(intent);
```

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. You are launching a third-party app. You have no control over the UI of whatever app responds to the `startActivity()` call and that `Intent`.